# Stationary distribution of mixture of Markov Chain with "complete" Markov Chain

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains, eigenvector

I already asked this question in StackExchange, but found little attention. So I'm just going to copy-paste my [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2502717/stationary-distribution-of-convex-combination-of-markov-chains) here.

Let $P$ be a stochastic matrix (of an irreducible Markov Chain) with stationary distribution $\pi^T$ (i.e. $\pi^T P = \pi^T$) and let further $E$ be the matrix of all $1$'s. 

Given an $\alpha \in [0,1]$, is it possible to find an expression for the stationary distribution of 
$$\alpha P + \frac{(1-\alpha)}{n}E,$$
depending on $\pi$ and $\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{1}$, where $\mathbb{1}$ is the vector of all $1$'s?

More generally; given two transition matrices of irreducible Markov Chains $P_1$ and $P_2$ with stationary distributions $\pi_1^T$ and $\pi_2^T$, respectively. Can one find a general formula to calculate the stationary distribution of 
$$\alpha P_1 + (1-\alpha)P_2 \quad,$$
for $\alpha \in [0,1]$?

Comment: You seem to be asking, if $P$ and $Q$ are row-stochastic primitive $n \times n$ matrices, then can the normalized left Perron eigenvector of a convex combination of $P$ and $Q$ be reconstructed from those of $P$ and $Q$ (and in the first case, $Q = E$)? (The answer is probably not.)  Or are you talking about Markov chains with infinite state space?

Comment: Yes exactly, that is what I am asking for. I know the general case might be too ambitious, but for $Q = E$ I had some hope...

And no, I am only talking about matrices, i.e. Markov Chains with finite state space.

Comment: @DavidHandelman Perhaps instead of an explicit computation, there are some useful bounds (in terms of $\alpha$) controlling the total variation distance of the stationary distribution of $\alpha P + (1 - \alpha)Q$ from the stationary distribution of $Q$?